# Join const char* in a string

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-ide

I am trying to put `const char*` variables in a string with concatenate, these are just initialising variables. Here is how I am trying to do that in `String input`:

```
const char* topic1 = "home/bathroomlight";
const char* topic2 = "home/bathroomfan";
const char* topic3 = "home/dressingroomlight";
const char* topic4 = "home/makeuplight";

const char* topic1_status = "home/bathroomlight/status";
const char* topic2_status = "home/bathroomfan/status";
const char* topic3_status = "home/dressingroomlight/status";
const char* topic4_status = "home/makeuplight/status";

String input = "{ \"Bath Room Light\" : { \"pin\" : 1, \"status\" : \"off\", \"type\" : \"light\", \"command_topic\" : "+  topic1 +", \"state_topic\" : "+topic1_status +" }, \"Bathroom Fan\" : { \"pin\" : 2, \"status\" : \"off\", \"type\" : \"fan\", \"command_topic\" : "+topic2+", \"state_topic\" : "+topic2_status+" }, \"Dressing Room Light\" : { \"pin\" : 4, \"status\" : \"off\", \"type\" : \"light\", , \"command_topic\" : "+ topic3 +", \"state_topic\" : "+ topic3_status +" }, \"Makeup Light\" : { \"pin\" : 3, \"status\" : \"off\", \"type\" : \"light\", \"command_topic\" : "+ topic4 +", \"state_topic\" : "+ topic4_status +" } }";
```

When I am trying to append these values to `input` String. Its not allowing me. As I guess the above value is in `const char*` how can I add that? any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: It may be worth simplifying your example. Also it might be useful to post the error message you are getting. Meanwhile does this work? `String input = String() + "{ \"Bath Room Light\" ...`?

Comment: @Galik sure I can share the error message as well.

Comment: @Galik I think your suggestion solved the problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that *native strings* (null terminated character arrays) and strings referred to through *character pointers* do not *concatenate* using the `+` operator. However the `Arduino` library's string class `String` does.

So first you have to construct a `String` class object and then *concatenate* your character arrays to that:

```
const char* s1 = "hello";
const char* s2 = "world";

String input = String() + s1 + " " + s2;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not allowing you because you can't concatenate `const char *`s.

To do so, you need to make one `std::string` object, afterwards you can add `const char *`s to that object (because `std::string` has `operator+` that takes in a `const char *`):

```
std::string str{ "{ \"Bath Room Light\" : { \"pin\" : 1, \"status\" : \"off\", \"type\" : \"light\", \"command_topic\" : " };
str += topic1 + ", \"state_topic\" : "+topic1_status +" ...
```

Comment: `std::string`  Is it a default variable type in C++

Comment: @user3201500 No. You have to include a header file `#include <string>`

Comment: I think I got the solution Galik just shared within comment :)

Comment: @user3201500 Then consider voting and accepting: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers